# set value for selectlist in Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

Consider the following Mechanize form object

```
#<Mechanize::Form
 {name "f1"}
 {method "POST"}
 {action "f.php"}
 {fields
  [hidden:0x4db4b02 type: hidden name: opflag value: ]
  [text:0x4db463e type: text name: lno value: 666]
  [selectlist:0x4db84dc type:  name: scode value: []]}
 {radiobuttons}
 {checkboxes}
 {file_uploads}
 {buttons [button:0x4db42ec type: button name: bt value:  Show Result ]}>
```

Here, I am able to set value of text field using

```
result_form = page.form('f1')
result_form.lno = '666'
```

But I am facing difficulty in setting value for `scode` selectlist. I have tried

```
result_form.field_with(name:"scode").option_with(value: "foo").click
```

it returns an ERROR as 
`undefined method`click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`
then, I tried

```
result_form.scode.value = 'foo'
```

But this returns `NoMethodError` as well. Any idea how to set value for selectlist in Mechanize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just:

```
result_form.scode = 'foo'
```

Comment: so simple! Not sure, why I didn't try this earlier :D

Answer (score 1):

`result_form["scode"] = "foo"` should do the trick. [Reference in the docs](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)